# Changes to Pandas transform function with any() between version 0.25 to 1.3

Tags: python, pandas

I am upgrading pandas in a legacy application and have noticed a change in the way a transform function works between versions with the any() method.

Starting with the below dataframe,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
            "group": ["EA", "EA", "WA", "WA"], 
            "unit_type": ["Weight", "Weight", "Weight", "Weight"], 
            "balance_status": ["Status One", None, None, None]
     })

group  ... balance_status
0    EA  ...       Status One
1    EA  ...           None
2    WA  ...           None
3    WA  ...           None
```

I perform a groupby() on a new df, check to see if any item in the group has a status and then set the status of all rows in the group to the only status. The following command.

```
calculated["balance_status"] = df.groupby(["group"])["balance_status"]\
                                 .transform(lambda x: x.any() if x.any() else None)
```

#### Pandas Version 0.25.3

The original form of this in version 0.25.3 gives the status as a string, which is desired.

```
  group  ... balance_status
0    EA  ...            Status One
1    EA  ...            Status One
2    WA  ...            NaN
3    WA  ...            NaN
```

#### Pandas Version 1.3.4

Upgrading pandas now gives the below output. The x.any() command now just produces "True", which is converted to an integer. This is in line with what I expected.

```
  group  ... balance_status
0    EA  ...            1.0
1    EA  ...            1.0
2    WA  ...            NaN
3    WA  ...            NaN
```

#### Workaround

My new version makes a generator of the series and takes the first non NaN value. This produces the correct result for us. We don't care if there are any other values after the first one.

```
calculated["balance_status"] = df.groupby(["group"])["balance_status"]\
  .transform(lambda x: next(item for item in x if item is not None) if x.any() else None)
```

#### Question

What changed with the any() function when used like this (the docs seem identical).

#### Edit

As pointed out by SeaBean, a more pandas-ish solution is to use the groupby().transform('first') method, as shown in the below question.

[How to use groupby.first() with transform function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57617994/how-to-use-groupby-first-with-transform-function)

Edited the question to be about the pandas changes that caused the change in behaviour.

Comment: To answer question 2, I think the problem is with `transform` and not `any`, and it could be related to [this bug fix](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.3.0.html#groupby-methods-agg-and-transform-no-longer-changes-return-dtype-for-callables) applied in version 1.3.0.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @Simone, this looks to be the change! Many thanks.

Comment: If you add something along these lines as an answer I will mark as the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately the question is closed and I can't add an answer, also I don't have enough reputation to vote for reopen.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.transform` with [`GroupBy.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html), as follows:

```
df.groupby(["group"])["balance_status"].transform('first')
```

Result:

```
0    Status One
1    Status One
2          None
3          None
Name: balance_status, dtype: object
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57617994/how-to-use-groupby-first-with-transform-function

Comment: Maybe should be dupe?

Comment: @jezrael  Oh, yes.  Will change to wiki then.

Comment: Legendary! This is the answer I was looking for. However, it does seem to be a dupe of the posted question. The second part of the question is answered by @Simone's comment above. I will edit the question to just this as I haven't found an answer to what had changed between the versions.

Comment: @davenenglish  It's arguable whether this is dup.  As the linked post is asking how to use it the `first` function within `transform`.  The person already knew he/she needs to use `first`.  This question is not the same.  You probably don't know you can use this function under this use case.  My answer provided info and sample code for this.  Anyway, I've marked it a community wiki where I don't receive any reputations nor points from SO.  I'm still glad to be helpful to you.

Comment: I've edited the question to be clearer. It's not about how or when to use first(), but about what changed between different versions of Pandas.

Answer (score 0):

*Are there any efficiency issues with the new method and is there a better way of achieving this.*

```
lambda x: next(item for item in x if item is not None) ...
```

does require knowledge of `lambda`s, `next`s and generators. This is not problem if anyone who would potentially read this code do know them, otherwise it might be beneficial to use more `pandas`-ish solution.